# Как сделать переменную видимой во всех контроллерах?

Tags: php, laravel

К примеру, в шапке сайта отображаются какие-то данные, которые берутся из БД. При переходе на другой маршрут, который обрабатывает другой контроллер, значение переменной теряется. Как сделать ее видимой для всех контроллеров?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29715813/laravel-5-global-blade-view-variable-available-in-all-templates

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Только это не для контроллеров а для шаблона, если вам нужно сделать переменную глобальной можно сделать это так `$this->app->singleton('template',function() use ($template) { return $template;});` и обращаться потом к ней в контроллерах так `app('template')`, делать это можно в AppServiceProvider в методе boot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При переходе на другой маршрут все данные во всех переменных теряются. PHP скриптовый язык и он не хранит состояния переменных. Они живы только пока выполняется скрипт. 
Нет ничего страшного хранить ваши данные в БД и получать их каждый раз.
Но если они все таки их получение очень ресурсоемко, то вы можете хранить их:
1. в cookies
2. в session

P.S. Если это данные о залогиненом пользователе, то возможно они уже есть в Auth::user()